# How to convert string lists into number lists

Tags: string-manipulation, input-forms

I have a string type list as follows

```
"{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{1,4,5},{5,6,7},{2,4,5}}}"
```

I want to turn it into a number list like

```
{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{1,4,5},{5,6,7},{2,4,5}}}
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html)